# From int array of 4096 elements to a float between 0 and 1

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am currently working on a project and I need to work with images.
However, my images are 64*64 sized, so when I load one, I have a 4096 int array.

I would like to convert this array to a float that is between 0 and 1 (and of course I will need the function that need to build an image from a float).

Do you have any idea or suggestion of how to do it ? 
Because I need to make an algorithm but I don't really know how to proceed.

Best regards and thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to convert each pixel in the array to float? Because it's impossible to convert an array to a single float value

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Well for me it is impossible but my teacher told me it is possible.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the real problem you're trying to solve that makes you think this would be a reasonable solution? Because to do what you're asking is not reasonable. Is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: I work in gesture recognitions and I work with a deep learning model.
I need to give to the model my images as datas .
The problem is  this model only accept a float that is between 0 and 1 as data.
And my teacher told me to not change the model.

Comment: A one-to-one turn an image into float is already built - concatenate all the ints in bitwise representation, add a 0 at start, there's your float, one and unique, but to store it with full precision you need as many bytes as for the starting image. And gesture recognition is a very different area that doesn't use floats of this lengths, you need an aggregate float that would mean "is this image like a gesture?" for example, and you won't be able to recreate the surece image from such a float.

Comment: it's possible to convert an *array of int* to an *array of float*, but not from an entire array to a floating-point value without the relation between the float and the array

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking," because it's obvious that the OP doesn't fully understand the task he's given, and he's asking how to do something that's clearly unreasonable and, if it were even possible, would be unlikely to solve whatever the real problem is that he's trying to solve.

Comment: How many BPP are the images?

Answer (score 1):

1. **The only way this could make some sense is if the image is binary (1 bit per pixel)**

   but even then the lossless naive conversion will take `64x64` bits which is far from what single `32bit` `float` can do. So there is some piece of info missing. To make this possible you need introduce some kind of compression but even that could be not enough unless lossy compression used. Anyway you should add some sample images so we see what are you dealing with.

   I am afraid the only usable compression for this would be using **DCT** (like in **JPEG**) on the full image. So do a **DCT** of the image and store only first few coefficients. for example if `4` bit coefficients used then you can store `32/4=8` coefficients which could be enough but hard to say if `4` bits will be enough to reconstruct the image back.
2. **In similar cases visual hashes are used**

   but you have no way to turn them back to the original image. They are pretty much the same as hashes but their binary representation is visually similar to the image.
3. **`float` is really not a good way for this**

   due to precision/rounding problems. You are loosing more bits then if just integer type would be used. Yes you can use `integer` type stored as `float` in integer format but the resulting `float` value can be jibberish with possibility of throwing exception if used as regular `float`.

   If the target `float` should be in range `<0.0,1.0>` then exceptions will not occur but you can not use exponent nor sign for storage limiting the usable bits to only `23` from original `32`.

When put all together without additional info I would:

1. **Do a DCT on `64x64` image matrix**
2. **use only `1x4bit + 6*3bit` top left corner matrix cells**
3. **encode into mantisa bits by concatenating**

   ```
   mantissa = coeff0+coeff1<<4+coef2<<7+coef3<<10+...
   ```
4. **set sign and exponent to set range to `<0.0,1.0>`**

   If I am not mistaking `sign=0` and `exponent=-1 + 32bit_float_bias`
5. **put the integer parts of `float` to floating value**

   ```
   union x { float f; DWORD dw; }
   DWORD sign=...,mantisa=...,exponent=...;
   x.dw=sign<<31;
   x.dw|=exponent<<23;
   x.dw|=mantisa;
   return x.f;
   ```

To obtain back the image (at least something close to it) reverse the steps. Yo can improve quality with introducing of some filters to get closer to your original images. But without actually seeing any of them is hard to tell which one to use or if even possible...